# how to write a infinite jms program

Tags: java, jms, xmltype

I build a jms program to receive xml data from my server-queue.

My problem is that physical memory is more and more bigger with the increasing data I get, and my jms got crash.

I already try oracle.xdb.XMLType.cleanupCache(true) and set up my jvm configuration, but I still cannot prevent it.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Your question is far too broad to be answered based on the information you've given.

Comment: sounds like you're not cleaning up somehow, such that messages aren't being correctly deleted from the queue, perhaps you have transactions that aren't being closed/committed/something?  as above, need more information